# How to uninstall the following?

Tags: software-uninstall

I've used the following:-

```
cd
wget --no-check-certificate -O autodl-setup http://sourceforge.net/projects/autodl-irssi/files/autodl-setup/download
sudo sh autodl-setup
```

to:-

> Install nginx
>   Install ruTorrent with multi-user support (http and https)
>   Install 1st party ruTorrent plugins
>   Install an encrypted FTP server (vsftpd)
>   Install rtorrent with xmlrpc-c support
>   Install the IRC auto downloader plugin (autodl-irssi)
>   Install Webmin
>   Install a startup script for rtorrent and Irssi

As suggested by [this](http://seedmybox.com/wiki/index.php?title=Install_Rutorrent) web page.
How do I uninstall all of that?

PS: I've install these "once and a half" (one complete installation, and another uncompleted one).

Answer (score 3):

You're in for a wild ride...

I've downloaded the script and it seems everything is build from source.

From what I have seen, in the folder where you ran the initial command, you should have a handful of files and folder, each for a specific program (rutorrent, nginx, etc.) go in each of them and run

```
make uninstall
```

If you are lucky, the uninstall file exist and it will remove all the file that each software `make install` copied onto the file system.

It also create more files but I'm not sure which. You can use `find / -type f -mtime -1` to list all file modified in the last day and locate what the script created.

If you are running a cloud or clean system, I would just re-provision/format it to really remove everything.